# Remove ads from embedded youtube video

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, adblock

So every answers regarding this problem is like:

> You cant do it unless you own the video and turn off the adsense
>   yourself.

But i see a possibility.

This is how adblockers works. When i ran chrome inspecter with adblockplus, i saw all the ad script requests blocked,

[image: see this]

i want to replicate the same but "in the website itself" using javascript

So that it will automatically block all ads.

Now why i want to do this ? because in my website, i dont want to annoy people with ads

Any solution ?

Comment: you still cannot for a video embedded in an iframe (unless you own the youtube domain, which i doubt), because you can't control its javascript. If you share other people's content, you share what comes with it.. as simple as that

Comment: but adblockers does it right ? what am i missing ?

Comment: possibly to hardcode a script that blocks every script received from googleads.g.doubleclick.net........

Answer (score 14):

Run this in your console.

```js
const clear = (() => {
    const defined = v => v !== null && v !== undefined;
    const timeout = setInterval(() => {
        const ad = [...document.querySelectorAll('.ad-showing')][0];
        if (defined(ad)) {
            const video = document.querySelector('video');
            if (defined(video)) {
                video.currentTime = video.duration;
            }
        }
    }, 500);
    return function() {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }
})();
// clear();
```

Comment: Complementing this answer, you can add some CSS to hide other ads in the page: #player-ads, ytd-ad-slot-renderer { display: none; } (The ads will still be there, but hidden)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution to achieve this -- is to make a browser extension like all adblocker do.

They are able to work because they are injecting javascript into *every* page and, roughly speaking, act like their javascript was served by YouTube themselves.